# AngularJS server form validation / Javascript: Parsing javascript variable "path"

Tags: javascript, json, validation, angularjs

I'm building an Angular app connected to an REST service which does server-side input validation.

e.g. if I send a object to the server with JSON like:

```
entry: { id: 5, name: "Test", locales: ["de","en"] }
```

I will get an response like:

```
{ id: 5, name: "Test", countries: ["de","en"],
    __errors__: [
        { field: "entry.name", message: "Test already in use" },
        { field: "entry.countries[1]", message: "'en' is not a country" }
    ]
}
```

*(quotation marks omitted for better reading)*

The `field` value is the "path" in javascriptish notation to the original value which caused the problem.

I'm somewhat free in what notation I will choose but I like this one because it's easy to read and integrates with the rest of the system. But I'm open to better suggestions.

The Question:

Now I want Angular to show which field failed with which message. What's the best way of doing this?

I tried things like `$scope.EditForm.$setValidity( field, message )` but it has no effect.

(nb: I'm using Angular with Bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Why not return an errors object that you bind to in your markup?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edeustace/UMRU9/2/

Here's a snippet:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
  <span ng-show="errors.name" style="color: red">{{errors.name}}</span>
  <br/>
  <input id="lastName" type="text" ng-model="lastName"></input>
  <span ng-show="errors.lastName" style="color: red">{{errors.lastName}}</span>
  <div ng-repeat="c in countries">
    <input ng-model="c" type="text"></input>
    <span style="color: red" ng-show="errors.countries[$index]">{{errors.countries[$index]}}    </span>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

    $scope.name = "Ed";
    $scope.lastName = "Eustace";
    $scope.countries = ["Ireland", "England"];
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.errors = {name: "Name in use", lastName: "", countries: ["Ireland is not available"] };
    }
});
```

That way you only need to wire up the ui and the update will happen for free due to data binding.

Comment: Hi ed. Thanks for you're reply and the effort. I'm not quiet sure because I'm having a hard time understanding angular's validation procedure but it seems your method is working around it. As I understand it (and I might be completely wrong) the `$error`, `$dirty` etc. stuff is there to do the "form control/validiation stuff" and is integrated "somehow" (again I'm having a hard time here) with what bootstrap does (e.g. showing the bubble-help).

Comment: I am still in a state where I find myself regularly deleting half of my code because I found out Angular already does what I just wrote ... in some Angular way. So currently I have a feeling that there is something "angularish" what's lurking there to be used.

Comment: But again: What I quiet like of this approach is the easiness it integrates on the HTML-side. Perhaps with the exception of the array stuff which forces N empty elements before the one which indicates the error if the list gets longer.

Comment: Ah ok - I didn't realise ng has that - will have a look at it see if you can assign an $errors object from the server result.